# Adding [theme] code to setup.sh file to deploy a Streamlit app on Heroku

Tags: heroku, streamlit

I deployed my Streamlit app on Heroku, the setup.sh file in my github that's used by Heroku has this code :

```
mkdir -p ~/.streamlit/

echo "
[server]
port = $PORT
enableCORS = false
headless = true
" > ~/.streamlit/config.toml
```

I didn't know how to add [theme] code this specific file config.toml

```
[theme]
primaryColor = "F36295"
backgroundColor = "#F0FF33"
secondaryBackgroundColor = "#3183D1"
textColor = "#03080C"
font = "sans-serif"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to make it work by putting this in my setup.sh:

```
mkdir -p ~/.streamlit/

echo "[theme]
primaryColor = ‘#84a3a7’
backgroundColor = ‘#EFEDE8’
secondaryBackgroundColor = ‘#fafafa’
textColor= ‘#424242’
font = ‘sans serif’
[server]
headless = true
port = $PORT
enableCORS = false
" > ~/.streamlit/config.toml
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw your question on the Youtube video we posted and have actually been trying to answer your question for days! (well days is an exaggeration, but many many times in the last 24 hours) For some reason, Youtube won't let me reply to you. :( I was finally able to get a reply up through the Streamlit account that doesn't seem to be disappearing (here's the link for you if you want to check: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mz12mlwzbVU&t=1s)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mz12mlwzbVU&t=1s)

All you have to do is add those configuration parameters directly into that config.toml file as you have them there. Literally, just copy-paste!

Marisa