# How to change the name of the streamlit app page?

Tags: python, heroku, streamlit

I have a web application deployed to Heroku. In the address line of the application, the name of the running file and the designation of the streamlit. How can I change this line with integer. Maybe you need to add some kind of configuration file?

I need to change the line "dashboard . Strealit"

[image]

Additionally, I ran into the fact that I have no application theme settings.
How can I enable them?

[image]

There is also a question about configuration files. They are located along the path: /.streamlit/
but if I place the code on GitHUB, then where should these files be located, in particular the file config.toml??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few questions here. To change your page name, you can set that a the beginning of your app code with:

```
st.set_page_config(
        page_title="My Page Title",
)
```

Streamlit theming was added in a recent update. To update your version and see the theme in the settings, you can run:

`pip install streamlit --upgrade`

and make sure to save the new version number in your requirements.txt.

Your're right, the `config.toml` file should be located inside a directory called `.streamlit` at the root of your app. You would need to commit that directory to your Github repo along with the rest of your files. Other config files, like editor configs, .gitignore, etc should be at the root of your project as well and can be committed with everything else.

Comment: This helped me a lot, thanks. And you can somehow remove the line • Streamlit? Found a way to fix this when running locally, but how can this be done on a published heroku app.

Comment: I'm not fully confident this will do it, but you can try editing the index.html in the site packages at venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/streamlit/static/index.html

Comment: Where can I find the menu, where can I fix it? Do I need to do this in the Heroku itself?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is solved using `st.set_page_config()`.
Streamlit has this attribute to change page title, page icon (favicon),layout, initial sidebar state, sidebar menu items.

Please check the Streamlit documentation answering your query from here,
[st.set_page_config](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/utilities/st.set_page_config#stset_page_config).

Use this code at the top of your streamlit_app.py file (if it has your main function)

```
st.set_page_config(page_title = "New Name")
```

Regarding the second question,
Use this code in setup.sh file, when ran in the Procfile this will create a dir with the theme configuration set in the config.toml under .streamlit directory.

```
mkdir -p ~/.streamlit/

echo "\
[general]\n\
email = \"your-email@domain.com\"\n\
" > ~/.streamlit/credentials.toml

echo "\
[theme]\n\
base='light'\n\
primaryColor='#3a70ec'\n\
backgroundColor='#FFD600'\n\
secondaryBackgroundColor = '#F0F2F6'\n\
textColor='#0e1862'\n\

[server]\n\
headless = true\n\
enableCORS=false\n\
port = $PORT\n\
" > ~/.streamlit/config.toml
```

You may also checkout this answer on the second question,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67001757/12007117

Thanks, upvote if found helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the app name, logo, etc. You should write the below code at the beginning of your script.

```
import streamlit as st 
from PIL import Image

image_directory = "C:\\Users\Documents\logo.PNG"
image = Image.open(image_directory)

PAGE_CONFIG = {"page_title":"MyApp", 
               "page_icon":image, 
               "layout":"centered", 
               "initial_sidebar_state":"auto"}

st.set_page_config(**PAGE_CONFIG)
```